# Imported Video file size changes on export to PDF

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, interactive

I'm working on an interactive PDF that has video and audio. https://www.dropbox.com/s/71pniir56v6r3vw/bl-brand-guidelines-video-d2.pdf?dl=0

The videos on this page are all the same size in InDesign, but when I export to PDF, their sizes change.

Do I have to clip their containers or resize the videos to match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resizing the videos with Adobe Media Encoder to ensure they were all the same width and checked that all of the frames were the same width and when I exported they were the right sizes.